Looping through cURL in SAS
First time working with API and cURL commands in SAS so please bear with me. I'm trying to iterate through several datasets that have at most 150 records. The API I'm working with can only ingest 150 records at a time. I'm working with 248 test records which yields 2 datasets: CCN_1_20240805 and CCN_2_20240805.
In the below, I've confirmed that :CCN_count evaluates to 2 so the loop will execute two times.
I've written the following macro:
macro API_calls;
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :CCN_count from datasets
;quit;

%do k = 1 %to &CCN_count;
   x curl -X POST '[HTTPS URL]'
   --header "Authorization: Bearer &access_token."
   --header 'Content_type: application/json'
   --data CCN_&k._&tday.
   --output test.txt;
%end;
%mend;
%API_calls;

The macro seems to run fine with no errors but when I look at the output test.txt, I see the following error:

I basically want to be sure that the macro is executing as expected through the 2 datasets but it's an API issue. I'm getting the token from another part of the code and putting it into the &access_token. variable which I have also confirmed is carrying the correct token generated.
Like I said above, first time working with API calls and loops in SAS to an extent.
I appreciate the feedback.

I would recommend using PROC HTTP instead, which has a number of features to help you identify if an error has occurred. You can use the PROC HTTP Status Response macro variables to determine this. Here is an updated version of your code that uses PROC HTTP with the &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE macro variable:
%macro api_calls;

    /* Count the number of rows */
    %let dsid      = %sysfunc(open(datasets));
    %let cnn_count = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobs));
    %let rc        = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

    %do i = 1 %to &cnn_count;
        proc http 
            url="URL HERE"
            method=post
            in="CNN_&i._&tday."
            ct="application/json"
            oauth_bearer="&access_token."
            ;
        run;  

        %if(&SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE NE 200) %then
            %put ERROR: CNN_&k._&tday. did not load correctly;
    %end;
%mend;
%api_calls;

You can make this more efficient by loading at most 150 values at a time. I do not know exactly what your datasets look like, but let's assume it's all concatenated into a single dataset for simplicity. Here's an example:
data test;
    do i = 1 to 350;
        value = cats("CNN_1_", i);
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

%macro api_calls(data=, max=);

    /* Determine the total number of rows */
    %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&data));
    %let n    = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid, nlobs));
    %let rc   = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
    
    %let n_files = %sysevalf(&n/&max, ceil);

    %let firstobs = 1;
    %let lastobs  = &max;

    /* Create files in groups of &max and send to the web server */
    %do i = 1 %to &n_files;
        filename payload temp;

        data _null_;
            set &data(firstobs=&firstobs obs=&lastobs);
            file payload;
            put value;
        run;

        proc http 
            url="URL HERE"
            method=post
            in=payload
            ct="application/json"
            oauth_bearer="&access_token"
            ;
        run;
        
        %if(&SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE NE 200) %then
            %put ERROR: Values &firstobs.-&lastobs. did not load correctly;

        filename payload clear;
    
        %let firstobs = %eval(&firstobs+&max);
        %let lastobs  = %eval(&lastobs+&max);
    %end;
%mend;
%api_calls(data=test, max=150);

